# How do you remove a row in a pivot table in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I used this code to create a pivot in pandas:

`table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Value (millions)', index=['TierA', 'TierB'], aggfunc=['count',np.sum])`

This gives me the pivot:

```
                      count               sum
                 Value (millions)   Value (millions)
TierA   TierB   
1        1             6                    400
2        0             0                     0
2        2             1                    300
```

In a pivot table how do I remove the [2,0,0,0] row? I tried the normal:

`table = table.drop(['TierA','TierB','count','sum'], axis =0)`

It didn't work, and neither did this:
`table = table.drop(['TierA','TierB','Value (millions)'], axis =0)`

Is what i'm trying to do possible? If so, how would I go about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on why you want to drop the row.

If it's because its index is (2,0), then write `table.drop(index = (2,0))` or `table.drop(index = 0, level = 1)`.

If it's because some of the values are 0, then write `table.loc[~(table.count == 0)]` or `table.loc[~(table.sum == 0)]`

I find it is often more convenient to `.loc` the inverse of the thing you want to remove, using `~` before the boolean condition, rather than dropping rows.

Comment: i'm getting a `KeyError: (2,0)` doing this, and I get a 'unary ~' error for the iloc method

Comment: Try putting parentheses around the condition after `~`. My bad.
I'm afraid my knowledge on Multiindexes is short, so I'll have to get back to you on that

Comment: @Noobcoder Could you post the result of `table.index`? I feel like some info might be missing if you're getting that key error.

Comment: ```MultiIndex([(1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 2.0), (2.0, 2.0)], names=['TierA', 'TierB'])```

Comment: `table.index` helped, thanks. I used :`table.drop(index=(1.0,2.0))` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your `pivot_table` has a MultiIndex and you have to pass a tuple to drop the row. Try with

```
table = table.drop((2, 0), axis = 0)
```

Comment: i'm getting a `KeyError: (2,0)` doing this